# Controlling Raspberry Pi GPIO ports using node.js

Tags: gpio, node.js, web-interface

I want to use node.js to parse data from a java script application back to the node.js server, I have accomplished this in a very rudimentary form and now I want to have the data turn on or off the GPIO pins on the Pi B+. I attempted doing that with this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pi-gpio a problem I ran into is that apparently it's file path is outdated and there isn't really any easy way around it. I was wondering if anyone knew of an ulterior way of interfacing with the GPIO pins in Node.js.

Comment: If all else fails you could use syscalls to the Python gpio package. It wouldn't be fast but it would always work

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using this module to switch and read GPIO pins, it is easy to handle and works very well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/onoff

Another module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpio

Comment: I find this module rather slow compared to the Python plugin and it is hard to configure pull-up / -down resistors
that one looks good: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpio

Comment: i did not know that one, will include it, thanx!

Answer (score -1):

Use this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd

And use the gpio shell commands.

Run gpio -h on raspberry pi terminal to find syntax.