# Pin on off engine javascript nodejs

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, voltage

I have a little engine linked at pin 1 and 3.
How can I turn it on and off throught nodejs?
Is there also a way to control how many volts are sent (to make the engine faster or slower)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling Raspberry Pi GPIO ports using node.js](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27990/controlling-raspberry-pi-gpio-ports-using-node-js)